# Python3 Selenium Repeating Value From Send Keys

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

**It is working now**

I want to iterate over each item in my list. Get the Google Search results and scrape a part of the results to add to a CSV. I tried that code and it still just repeats the value until it hits the limit of the search bar.

I am using Selenium and Python3 to gather some data via Google searches. I have successfully used Python3 and Selenium to scrape before where I iterated through a list of URLs, loaded the URL and scraped.

I thought it should work the same way for this. But it's not. I am just trying to pull in the first item from my list and put that in the Google Search bar. When it does, it just repeats the text over and over until it hits the limit of the search bar.

Any help to understand what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

When I create a variable of my text it just sends it once into the search field. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**Example**: My first item is: "What time is it in Mobile,AL"
When it's put into the search bar it just repeats like this: What time is it in Mobile,AL,What time is it in Mobile,AL,What time is it in Mobile,AL,What time is it in Mobile,AL,.

Below is the code that I'm using to loop through the items. **It is working now**

I really appreciate any insight! Thank you!

```
f = open('Google_Loop.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
search = []
for column in csv_f:
  search.append(column[11])
position = 0
while position <len(search):
     browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
     browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(search[position])
     browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 
     text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]").text
     data=text
     df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Search Results'], index=[0])
#Creates The Filename, then appends the DF to the file on each iteration
     filename=f"Search Results.csv"
     df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', header=False, index=False)
     position = position + 1
```

Comment: Is your while loop really just typing in the text field, or is there more to your code?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't anything else going on with it. Like I said, I tested it with a variable and it worked fine.

Comment: So the only thing this code does is loop over lines in a CSV file and types them in the search box on Google? If that is all the code is doing, then it is doing precisely what you told it to do. It just types in the search box over and over again.

Comment: What do you **expect** the code to do?

Comment: Just enter the first item of my list ""What time is it in Mobile,AL" into the Google Search Field. If I create a variable called search = "What time is it in Mobile,AL" and send that. It just sends it once. I'm not sure what I'm missing to cause it to repeat the entry so many times

Comment: @GregBurghardt, why did you down-vote my post? I indicated in the OG that I had success with this type of iterative loop before with URLs. I indicated the issue I was having and even gave an example of what the output was. Just because your suggestions did not work is not an appropriate reason to downvote.

Comment: I've tried a number of times to get some clarity about what the problem is, and what the expected behavior was. You posted a `while` loop that does nothing but type in a text box. At this point I don't know how else to help. At first I thought you just posted part of the `while` loop, but from what I gather that is the entirety of your code. If there is more to your while loop, please add that to your question. Otherwise your code is doing exactly what it is being told to do: type in a text field repeatedly, then quit.

Comment: Please post the rest of the while loop in your question.